# Correct way to show a QSplashScreen

Tags: splash-screen, pyqt6

I am having problems displaying a splashscreen to have user wait to complete startup.

Relevant code (lifted from Qt docs) is as follows:

```
from PyQt6 import uic, QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ... some very long initialization...


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('resources/dark-arisen.jpg')
    splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(pixmap)
    splash.show()
    app.processEvents()
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    splash.finish(mw)
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`MainWindow.__init__()` takes several seconds to complete because it loads and parses a not-so-small XML file.

Apparently something is wrong with initial `app.processEvents()` because net effect is I see nothing until the initialization is complete, then splash screen flashes very briefly, immediately followed by the main GUI display.

I am working under Linux Debian/Cinnamon, if relevant.

What am I missing?

Comment: What if you add a further `QApplication.processEvents()` just right after the `super().__init__()` call of the main window (supposing that the "very long initialization" happens after that)? It would also help to know what would be the purpose of the parsed XML file, as it may be possible to try to move it to a separate thread (as long as it doesn't directly cause creation of UI elements, of course)..

Comment: @musicamante: placing a `processEvents()` right after `super().__init__()` does not suffice, but putting it after most of GUI initialization and right before the XML parsing does the trick. I need the XML loaded because program is actually an editor for that file so it doesn't make much sense to open a window and then wait for it to be filled.

Comment: Well, it could make sense, if done properly: unless the UI layout is *strongly* affected by the loading of the XML, you could just create and show the whole UI, then show a modal dialog (even a QProgressDialog) while loading, and periodically call for `processEvents()` in the meantime within the XML loading function, so that it wouldn't freeze the UI, it would prevent unwanted user interaction, and it won't affect UX too much, since the user will know that something is happening.